# ManyToMany association. How to add owner entities to inverse entities?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have 2 entities and manytomany association:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="m2m_table1")
 */
class Table1
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false, options={"unsigned":true})
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Table2", inversedBy="table1", fetch="LAZY", cascade="all")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="m2m_links",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="table1_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="table2_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    private $table2;
    ...
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="m2m_table2")
 */
class Table2
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false, options={"unsigned":true})
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Table1", mappedBy="table2", fetch="LAZY", cascade="all")
     */
    private $table1;
    ...
}
```

And I want to have opportunity to add inverse entities to owner entities and vice versa. I can add inverse entities to owner entities, but I can't add owner entities to inverse entities.

```
$table1 = $em->find('XxxM2mBundle:Table1', 1);
$table2 = $em->find('XxxM2mBundle:Table2', 1);
$table2->addTable1($table1);
$em->flush($table2);
```

Link is not added. Example is simplified, in fact there are 2 forms, 1-st to adjust links for Table1 and 2-nd to adjust links for Table2. I use  `Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType` for it. 2-nd form doesn't work with this configuration.

Form class:

```
namespace Xxx\M2mBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type as FormType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type as DoctrineFormType;

class Table2 extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->setMethod('post')
            ->add('name', FormType\TextType::class, [
                'required' => true,
                'label' => 'Name',
            ])
            ->add('table1', DoctrineFormType\EntityType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
                'class' => 'Xxx\\M2mBundle\\Entity\\Table1',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'label' => 'Table1',
            ])
            ->add('save', FormType\SubmitType::class, [
                'label' => 'Save',
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => 'Xxx\\M2mBundle\\Entity\\Table2',
        ]);
    }
}
```

I have changed association for `Table2` to:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Table1", inversedBy="table2", fetch="LAZY", cascade="all")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="m2m_links",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="table2_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="table1_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
private $table1;
```

It helped, but I think that it is not good decision, and now I get error `The table with name 'm2m_links' already exists.` when I try to update schema `./bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql --force`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand about [Owning and Inverse side of the association](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html).

This is how you are able to work smoothly with ManyToMany associations:

1. generate the two enities you need with the CLI e.g.

   `bin/console doctrine:generate:entity`
2. go to [doctrine association mapping for ManyToMany bidirectional](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional)
3. add the annotations and the constructors to your Entities. Do not forget to write `ORM\` before your annotations. Change Entity and table names to your own situation.
4. extend the ManyToMany annotation at the Owner side or both sides of your relationship with the cascade={"persist"} option. e.g.

   `@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", inversedBy="images", cascade={"persist"})`
5. automatically generate needed methods and update the schema with the CLI.

   `bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle`

   `bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force`
6. add a [__toString()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) method to both entities.
7. If you want to be able to add owner-entities on inversed entity you could make a small change in the add and remove method of the inversed entity as the example below shows.

example:

```
# Tag entity

public function addImage(\AppBundle\Entity\Image $image)
{
    $image->addTag($this); // new rule!
    $this->images[] = $image;

    return $this;
}

public function removeImage(\AppBundle\Entity\Image $image)
{
    $image->removeTag($this); // new rule!
    $this->images->removeElement($image);
}
```

8. add `'by_reference' => false` to the entity form field options

example:

```
class TagType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
                ->add('name')
                ->add('images', EntityType::class, array(
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'class' => 'AppBundle:Image',
                    'by_reference' => false # HERE!
                ))
        ;
    }

// ..
```

Comment: It works with simplified example, and doesn't work with forms.

Comment: It works with forms too on my side. Can you show your formType class ? (should live in the SomeBundle/Form directory)

Comment: Yes, I've added

Comment: Have to excuse myself. It did not work with forms like you said. My fault. But got it working now. I have updated my answer on steps 7 and 8.